# Query works in console, but not externally

Tags: mongodb, nosql, realm

I'm working with MongoDB's Realm cloud computing service.

As the title suggests, the query runs fine in the console, but not when executed externally (through Postman).

Key Points:

- When logged, the moviesList is empty when externally triggered, but has data when in console.
- I have set up a default rule for the collection providing read/write access.
- It returns empty results externally, no errors caught.

```js
    // Data can be extracted from the request as follows:

    let qry = {}
    if(query.year) {
      qry = {"year": {$eq: parseInt(query.year)}}
      console.log("year: " + query.year);
    } else if (query.title) {
      qry = {"title": {$eq : query.title}}
      console.log("title: " + query.title);
    } else {
      console.log("NO PARAMETERS");
    }
    
    // Querying a mongodb service:
    const doc = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("sample_mflix").collection("movies");

    
    let moviesList = doc.find(qry).limit(5).toArray();
    let jsonList = JSON.stringify(moviesList);
    
    // return jsonList;
    if(response)
      response.setBody(jsonList);
      
    console.log(console.log("JSON: " + jsonList));
      
    return jsonList;
```

Console Output:

```
> ran at Tue Jan 18 2022 13:17:16 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
> took 323.632668ms
> logs: 
NO PARAMETERS
JSON: [{"_id":"573a1390f29313caabcd4135","plot" ...
undefined
> result: 
"[{\"_id\":\"573a1390f29313caabcd4135\",\"plot\" ...
```

Not entirely certain what the "undefined" below the one console log happens to be.

Postman response:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are those console logs from that script?

Comment: I think it might've been slightly different. I was playing around between edits. I've updated with the code that made the console output.

Comment: shouldn't you just send the response? Also, what is setBody?

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't change anything. Response is a callback, I believe. Not certain it needed returning. Regardless, it return an empty array string.

Comment: app not many are into realm yet, but seems very cool, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a permissions issue to the database.

The console was obviously providing me with root permissions, so it was working.

The API was failing, but no errors (as far as I could tell) were being thrown. It just returned an empty set.

[image]